# How can I set up vue and core ui?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, core-ui

I want to make website using https://coreui.io/vue/.

what needs to be installed to create the project and how to set it up? besides how do I install coreui on my website without having to put all the templates on the website. so I only need the css. not all

or is there a template that is better than coreui?

thanks

Comment: Is there no one who can help me? :(

Answer (score 1):

the first page of the documentation literally spells out how to add CSS to the project.

[Docs](https://coreui.io/docs/getting-started/introduction/)

> Copy-paste the stylesheet link into your head before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css">
```

If you want to setup a starter template then simply use the follow:

```
git clone https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template.git my-project
# clone the repo

$ cd my-project
# go into app's directory

$ npm install
# install app's dependencies
```

edit: Forgot to mention to check out [Vuetfiy](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) - my personal favourite UI library for Vue

Comment: from your answer, I conclude that there are 2 choices here, namely coreui and vuetify. so I have to choose one of the coreui and vuetify for my css display? or can I combine the two?

Comment: you should take a look over both and make a decision as to which most suits your needs. With Vuetify, you can simply scroll through the UI Components and take a look at their examples to get some ideas as to what it is capable of.

Im not a CSS expert but I would not recommend mixing the frameworks as you may well get clashes and unexpected behaviour.

Comment: okay. I have already made a decision, using vuetify. but if I look at the vuetify documentation, the UI component is very small

Comment: I'm just afraid it will be difficult later to convert the prototype (using Adobe XD) to html css using vuetify